# Error Json in swift 3

Tags: swift

this code JSON not work on swift 3 and i got err in swift 3 how to fix it ?

```
func dataJsonFromURL(url:String) -> NSArray {

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)! as URL) {
        return ((try! JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])) as! NSArray)
    }
    else {
        return data
    }
}
```

how to fix it to work in swift 3

Comment: Where do u have error?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3

Comment: The error is OP copy-pasted some non swift3-code and does not know how to properly google and / or search stackoverflow for the appropriate resources.

Comment: the error in line  if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)! as URL) and return data how to fix it ?

Comment: ERROR : ViewController.swift:29:23: 'init(contentsOfURL:options:)' has been renamed to 'init(contentsOf:options:)'

Comment: Don't use `NSArray`. Use a Swift array. Don't use `NSURL`, use `URL`. Don't use `NSData`, use `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use NSData in Swift 3. It has been changed to Data. [How to convert NSData to Data in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683099/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-data-in-swift-3)

Comment: @OsamaAltmeme did you look at the link I posted?

Answer (score 0):

```
func dataJsonFromURL(url:String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let realUrl = URL(string: url) {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: realUrl)
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [String: Any] {
                return json
            }
        } catch {
            //error
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: then how i can use url ? i was use data = (dataJsonFromURL(url: "http://www.???.com/test.php" but now i got error how to use it ?

Comment: @OsamaAltmeme you should do some research yourself on swift 3 :)

Comment: please help me for this i was use : var data = [] then to call url data = (dataJsonFromURL(url: "???.com/test.php" but i get error how to fix it