# How to create Data from CMSampleBuffer With Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

We can convert CMSampleBuffer to NSData with following function.
But we could not find a way to convert it to Data.

We tried using

```
   Data(bytes: <#T##UnsafeRawPointer#>, count: <#T##Int#>)
```

instead of

```
   NSData(bytes: <#T##UnsafeRawPointer?#>, length: <#T##Int#>)
```

but no luck.
Is there anyone who could do it.

```
func frameData() -> NSData {

        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)
        let src_buff = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!)
        let nsdata = NSData(bytes: src_buff, length: bytesPerRow * height)

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))


        return nsdata

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert NSData to Data as like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49074149/3420996?

Comment: Just seconds ago I tried this let data = Data(bytes: src_buff!, count: bytesPerRow * height) and seems to be working. (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just used

```
       let data = Data(bytes: src_buff!, count: bytesPerRow * height)
```

instead of

```
     let nsdata = NSData(bytes: src_buff, length: bytesPerRow * height)
```

The key is here was !  after src_buff for Data.
Because xCode was showing some errors which is not related ! usage I could not understand ! was needed.